# How can I disable the splash screen and intro videos?

Tags: borderlands-2

When I open borderlands through Steam, it opens a menu where I have to click play a second time.  Then another splash screen  Then it goes through these annoying, but at least skippable, intro videos.  Is there any way I can bypass all this and have the game go directly to the opening menu?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## Disabling the startup movies

It is possible to disable the startup movies by editing the WillowEngine.ini file located in your Documents/My Games folder and commenting out a few lines which define which videos play when the game launches.

The default location for the Borderlands 2 config folder within your Documents folder is;

> %USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\Borderlands 2\WillowGame\Config\

Simply edit the file 'WillowEngine.ini' and find the following variables:

```
[FullScreenMovie]
StartupMovies=2K_logo
StartupMovies=Gearbox_logo
StartupMovies=NVidia
StartupMovies=Loading
SkippableMovies=2K_logo
SkippableMovies=Gearbox_logo
SkippableMovies=Attract
SkippableMovies=NVidia
```

...and comment out the `StartupMovies` lines as follows;

```
[FullScreenMovie]
;StartupMovies=2K_logo
;StartupMovies=Gearbox_logo
;StartupMovies=NVidia
;StartupMovies=Loading
SkippableMovies=2K_logo
SkippableMovies=Gearbox_logo
SkippableMovies=Attract
SkippableMovies=NVidia
```

This should cause the game to skip over these startup movies when you start Borderlands 2.

## Disabling the launcher

To disable the Borderlands 2 launcher, set the following launch option within Steam:

`-NoLauncher`

To change launch options with Steam, do the following;

- Right-click on 'Borderlands 2' under the game Library in Steam and select Properties
- Under the General tab click the 'Set launch options...' button
- Enter the launch options as per above and click OK
- Close the Borderlands 2's 'Properties' window and launch the game

This will disable the 'Play/Setup' screen upon launching Borderlands 2 from within Steam.

<sup>Sources: [Disabling Intro Movies](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Borderlands_2#Disabling_Intro_Movies) | [Disable Launcher](http://www.nerdyandlovingit.com/disable-startup-movies-in-borderlands-2/) | [How to set launch properties](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1040-JWMT-2947)</sup>

Comment: I have not found any specific method of disabling the splash screen, although seemingly in Borderlands 1 there wasn't an official method either and [people just removed the .bmp](http://www.necrophix.com/forums/index.php?topic=2096.0) which caused the game to skip it when it failed to find the image for the splash.

Comment: Yea, I tried renaming it.  It basically just displays nothing for the same duration it would display the splash screen.

Comment: One tweak to your excellent info: right above the "StartupMovies" settings, my WillowEngine.ini file included the line "bForceNoMovies=FALSE". Setting this to "TRUE" disabled all the movies for me in a single setp.

Comment: @FeralChimp Probably not a good idea. You don't know what that does exactly. That switch could control cutscenes as well, and apparently other UE games [crash on certain screens](http://www.chivalrythegame.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=4168) if you set this to true.

Comment: Thanks @lunboks, it can't hurt to err on the side of caution. I can say that I've run this configuration for (too) many hours on both a workstation and a laptop with no crashes. I guess I'm not sure whether I'm missing cutscenes. I've definitely seen some, but maybe that was without bForceNoMovies. I'll try it both ways to see.

Comment: Update: I just briefly started two new games, one with bForceNoMovies as FALSE and one as TRUE. Even on TRUE I still had to sit through Claptrap's lengthy intro video, and I saw the cutscene where Knuckle Dragger swings in and steals Claptrap's eye. So in this very brief test with two cutscenes/cinematics, things looked the same. Maybe there are other kinds of cutscenes/cinematics I haven't hit yet?

Comment: in Linux the file is `.steam/SteamApps/common/Borderlands 2/steamassets/willowgame/config/defaultengine.ini`